# How output field in $view->result?

Tags: views

I need get to field views in calendar module template.

`print_r($view->result)` output this: https://jsfiddle.net/36pbj7bb/

How output event_calendar_status?

I type this:

```
<?php print $view->result[0][_field_data][nid][entity][event_calendar_status][und][0][tid];   ?>
```

But I get:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views rows and entities are objects so I would think it should be this:

```
$view->result[0]->_field_data['nid']['entity']->event_calendar_status[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['tid'];
```

but I'm guessing a little bit.

Also note the use of quotes in the array keys and the use of the [LANGUAGE_NONE](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7) constant instead of 'und' for the field language.

If you still have trouble then try using the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module to see the structure of the view object variable.

There is information available via Google for how to use the Devel module to debug.